# Extract data from list of list of data frame in pandas and make one data frame from it

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

```
df_net = pd.DataFrame(j) //// where j is the list of list of data frames
```

**when i run the above command and make the data frame from the list j the data frame i am seeing is given below**

[image: This is what i am seeing each rows has further 365 entries in it]

**Each Row of  this data frame has further 365 entries and 5 columns**

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: it has literally 4 dimensions for data input. use something powerfull and versatile for 4D inputs

Comment: This is all what i am seeing. it has many entries and i am new to python that's why i have posted                                                                                                                  
it looks like this except each row has 365 elements      
0   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
3   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to my question in a way that first i declared a dictionary of the nested list of the data frames

```
dataframe_net = {i: j[i] for i in range(0, len(j))} ##### where j is the list
```

then i made the data frames from each dictionary items

```
df_net =pd.concat(
    (i_value_df.assign(date=i_key) for i_key, i_value_df in dataframe_net .items()))
```

The resultant data frame was the combination of the data frames in the nested list j